# Hoodie postinstall failed: process.env.PWD is undefined

Tags: windows-10, npm-install, hoodie

I'm trying to experiment with hoodie, but the npm install isn't working for me.

Windows 10
Node 7.0.0
NPM 3.10.8

```
npm ERR! hoodie@28.1.2 postinstall: `node ./bin/setup.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hoodie@28.1.2 postinstall script 'node ./bin/setup.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hoodie package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/setup.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hoodie
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hoodie
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby\npm-debug.log
F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby [gh-pages +0 ~3 -0]> node -v
v7.0.0
F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby [gh-pages +0 ~3 -0]> npm -v
3.10.8
```

The problem is with the post-install script, specifically, `process.env.PWD` is undefined, but the script is trying to access it:

```
> hoodie@28.1.2 postinstall F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby\node_modules\hoodie
> node ./bin/setup.js

F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby\node_modules\hoodie\bin\setup.js:7
var installIntoApp = process.env.PWD.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\dev\mrkennedy-ca\countby\node_modules\hoodie\bin\setup.js:7:37)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

Advice? THIS install is inside of an existing package, but I get the same result when attempting the install on a fresh package as in the [quickstart directions](http://docs.hood.ie/en/latest/guides/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a change that was only released a day ago via https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie/pull/760. I’ve created an issue that you can follow to be notified when the problem is resolved: https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie/issues/763

for the time being, please try `npm install --save hoodie@28.1.1` which installs the previous version.

Comment: Timing is everything, hey? Haha. Thanks.

Comment: The problem should be resolved now via https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie/releases/tag/v28.1.3